# MySQL LOWER() function not multi-byte safe for the º character?

Tags: mysql, symbols, multibyte, lowercase

When I encoding the following character to UTF-8:

```
º
```

I get:

```
Âº
```

Then with Âº stored as a field value, I select the field with the LOWER() function and get

```
âº
```

I was expecting it to respect that the value is a multi-byte character and thus will not perform the LOWER on it.

Expected:

```
Âº
```

I am I not understanding correctly that the LOWER() function is suppose to be multi-byte safe as stated in the manual? (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lower)

Or am I doing something wrong here?

I am running MySQL 5.1.

**EDIT**

The encoding on the table is set to UTF-8.  The session encoding is default latin1.

Here are my repro steps.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  test_field VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO test_table(test_field) VALUES('Âº');

SELECT LOWER(test_field) FROM test_table;
```

Comment: What is the encoding on the column? What is the encoding on the session?

Comment: The table encoding is utf8, the session is default latin1.  I added my reproduction steps to what I'm doing.  Am I doing something wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that when you're inserting `VALUES('Âº')`, you're inserting the two characters `Â` and `º`, and **not** the UTF-8 representation of the single character `º`?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO test_table(test_field) VALUES('Âº');
```

Will insert a 2 character string, which has the correct LOWER() of "âº"

- Lower("Â") is "â"
- Lower("º") is "º"

If you want to insert "º" then make sure you have

```
SET NAMES 'utf-8';
```

and

```
INSERT INTO test_table(test_field) VALUES('º');
```

Comment: Eugen, is there a way to set the default character set for MySQL besides having to SET NAMES every session?

Comment: Yes: "With the mysql client, if you want to use a character set different from the default, you could explicitly execute SET NAMES every time you start up. However, to accomplish the same result more easily, you can add the --default-character-set option setting to your mysql command line or in your option file. For example, the following option file setting changes the three connection-related character set variables set to koi8r each time you invoke mysql:

[mysql]
default-character-set=koi8r"

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: @PHPV to be honest I don't know. When running from PHP my database class does this (SET NAMES 'utf-8') for me, so I only look into that corner if it starts to smell.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I am not understanding this correctly.

The 'º' character is not a UTF-8 encoded string, not sure why it should be stored as such in the table.

Comment: Why is  'º' not UTF-8 encoded? Encoding isn't something you "see" in a String, it's the internal representation of the string.